# Database migration from Mysql To SQLServer using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to write a script which will transfer daily data from Mysql to SQL server.
I have decided to do this using hibernate.

There are three databases in mysql called db1, db2 & db3. I want to transfer data from all these databases to SQL server. Table structure on SQL server is identical to MYSQL. Simply we can say this script is to take backup of mysql data on sql server.

Now my question is:

1. Is there any other simple method to do this?
2. How can I connect to 3 different databases (db1,db2,db3) of mysql as well as sql server using hibernate?

in `hibernate.cfg.xml` url property takes one database name only:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1</property>
```

So in this way I need to write 6 `hibernate.cfg.xml` files to connect to mysql as well as sql server.

Answer (score 0):

One of the constructors for Configuration does take a file path:

```
public Configuration configure(String resource) throws HibernateException {
                standardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure( resource );
                // todo : still need to have StandardServiceRegistryBuilder handle the "other cfg.xml" elements.
                //              currently it just reads the config properties
                properties.putAll( standardServiceRegistryBuilder.getSettings() );
                return this;
}
```

So... what you'll need to do is copy your hibernate.cfg.xml file as many times as you need and configure different sessions using the [standard way](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-testing/src/main/java/org/hibernate/testing/junit4/BaseCoreFunctionalTestCase.java).